# ToggleClass

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго времени суток.
Проблема в следующем: есть таблица .table, в каждой строке есть несколько столбцов, в которых ссылка, в которой есть span .down. 
Как при помощи jq при клике на определённую ссылку затоглить класс и убрать все остальные классы в этой строке, при последующем клике на др. ссылку делать то же самое?
Делаю так: [вот](http://jsfiddle.net/ygzcp4rz/), но при повторном клике класс .down пропадает. Направьте на правильный путь. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При удалении обоих классов, по `toggle` появляются оба класса и исчезают тоже оба, поэтому добавляем третий класс при отсутствии стрелочки, и если он есть у элемента, то добавляем `down` или `up`, и дальше уже всё нормально:

http://jsfiddle.net/ygzcp4rz/1/